# Installing software with dependencies

Tags: software-installation, apt, software-compilation

I want to install the last version of Minimodem on my Raspi.

If I do:

```
sudo apt-get install minimodem
```

I obtain the version 0.8.1, which is not the last one that the author has released.
The last version incorporates some features that I need.

Here: ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/minimodem there is the compiled version 0.19 (which is the one I want to install) for armhf, but when I do:

```
 wget ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/minimodem/minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb
```

And then I try to install it:

```
 sudo dpkg -i minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb
```

There is a depedency problem:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo dpkg -i minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb 
(Reading database ... 72372 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace minimodem 0.8.1-1 (using minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement minimodem ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of minimodem:
 minimodem depends on libfftw3-single3; however:
  Package libfftw3-single3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing minimodem (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 minimodem
```

The libfftw3-single3 seems to be not available, if I try to install it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install libfftw3-single3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libfftw3-single3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libfftw3-single3' has no installation candidate
```

Is there some way to fix it and install the last version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution is gitting minimodem and compiling your own version.
You will need to:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kamalmostafa/minimodem.git
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
cd minimodem
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

At the end, you will have:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ minimodem -V
minimodem 0.19
Copyright (C) 2011-2013 Kamal Mostafa <kamal@whence.com>
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Kamal Mostafa <kamal@whence.com>.
```

... and

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ minimodem --benchmarks
minimodem 0.19 benchmarks
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
  generate-tones-lut1024-S16-mono
    frames count:       480000
    audio playtime:     10.000000 sec
    elapsed runtime:     0.084909 sec
    performance:        5653110 samples/sec
  generate-tones-lut1024-FLOAT-mono
    frames count:       480000
    audio playtime:     10.000000 sec
    elapsed runtime:     0.087484 sec
    performance:        5486717 samples/sec
  generate-tones-nolut-S16-mono
    frames count:       480000
    audio playtime:     10.000000 sec
    elapsed runtime:     1.642639 sec
    performance:        292212 samples/sec
  generate-tones-nolut-FLOAT-mono
    frames count:       480000
    audio playtime:     10.000000 sec
    elapsed runtime:     1.595292 sec
    performance:        300885 samples/sec
```

I've made some TX and RX tests. Everything is working fine.

You may do this quick and dirty test:

```
wget http://www.nonstopsystems.com/radio/snds-radio/radio-audio-rtty-170-45.wav
minimodem --read -a rtty --file radio-audio-rtty-170-45.wav
```

... and you will get:

```
### CARRIER 45.45 @ 1100.0 Hz ###
??? THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG 1234567890 ??? THE QUICK
BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG 1234567890
```

==================================================================================
For historical purposes only

==================================================================================
Try this way:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb
```

==================================================================================

Comment: I got the next error: 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo dpkg -i libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb
dpkg: regarding libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb containing libfftw3-single3:armhf:
 libfftw3-single3 breaks libfftw3-3 (<< 3.3.3-1)
  libfftw3-3:armhf (version 3.3.2-3.1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb (--install):
 installing libfftw3-single3:armhf would break libfftw3-3:armhf, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb

Comment: Did you try sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb ?

Comment: Seems to be dependency problems...:

De-configuring libfftw3-3:armhf ...
Replacing files in old package libfftw3-3:armhf ...
Setting up libfftw3-single3:armhf (3.3.3-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfftw3-3:armhf:
 libfftw3-single3:armhf (3.3.3-7) breaks libfftw3-3 (<< 3.3.3-1) and is installed.
  Version of libfftw3-3:armhf to be configured is 3.3.2-3.1.

dpkg: error processing libfftw3-3:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfftw3-3:armhf

Comment: Ok, now redo sudo dpkg -i libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb and it will be installed

Comment: Now its installed, but when I try to launch it:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ minimodem
Illegal instruction

Comment: Did you repeat sudo dpkg -i minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb ?

Comment: Yes, I did. 1- sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb  2- sudo dpkg -i libfftw3-single3_3.3.3-7_armhf.deb 3- sudo dpkg -i minimodem_0.19-1_armhf.deb. 

I have the same error: Illegal instruction

Comment: I will take another look ... Do not give up !!

Comment: Final answer posted. HTH. Remember to uninstall the old "buggy" version.

Comment: Working fine! Thanks a lot! Bytheway, did you try to transmit and receive at the same time? Demodulating & decodifying from an audio file works fine, but I can do it properly 'live'. PulseAudio consumes a lot of resources even when the resampling method is set to trivial.

Comment: No, I didn't. Sorry for delay. Did you? Is everything ok?

Comment: After some benchmarks I realized that PulseAudio was consuming too much resources and the only way to demodulate a transmission live with SoftModem was by means of using ALSA without PulseAudio on the top. It works well but with an extrange behaviour, the data seems to be demodulated by bursts: it demodulates 5 seconds of transmission quickly, then stops during 4-5 seconds, and again in a burst demodulates the signal. That does not happen when the input is a sound file, only when the data is coming from the microphone.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Others will really find it very useful.